# Android Calendar get current day of week as string

Tags: java, android, calendar, null, dayofweek

i tried to get a string with the name of the actual weekday this way:

```
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

            if (c.get(Calendar.MONDAY) == dayOfWeek) weekDay = "monday";
            else if (c.get(Calendar.TUESDAY) == dayOfWeek) weekDay = "tuesday";
            else if (c.get(Calendar.WEDNESDAY) == dayOfWeek) weekDay = "wednesday";
            else if (c.get(Calendar.THURSDAY) == dayOfWeek) weekDay = "thursday";
            else if (c.get(Calendar.FRIDAY) == dayOfWeek) weekDay = "friday";
            else if (c.get(Calendar.SATURDAY) == dayOfWeek) weekDay = "saturday";
            else if (c.get(Calendar.SUNDAY) == dayOfWeek) weekDay = "sunday";
```

but `weekDay` stays always null and i actually have no idea why because the debugger says that `dayOfWeek` is 5 so i should be equal to `c.get(Calendar.THURSDAY)`

Comment: What is the *type* of `c.get(`? An `int`? Or the `Integer` reference type?

Comment: just use an array, why do you need if else. String[] days=new String[]{"Monday".... although it is safer to actually instantiate inside a method. days[Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.Day_OF_WEEK)] should do the trick. month and day are 0 based in the utils package

Answer (score 83):

As simple as this

```
sCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String dayLongName = sCalendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: So that it uses the default locale... Is it able to use `Context` to get the locale?

Comment: @EarthEngine `Locale.getDefault()` should return the locale of the android device.

Answer (score 64):

I accomplished this by doing the following:

```
String weekDay;
SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.getDefault());

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
weekDay = dayFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
```

- Use the day format for "EEEE" will return the full weekday name, i.e. Tuesday
- Use the day format for "E" will return the the abbreviated name, i.e. Tue
- Another benefit to returning this format in Android is that it will translate the weekday based on the locale.

You will want to review the [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to learn more. I think this is the cleanest approach in that you do not need a **switch** or **if** statement if your only need is to get the string value.

Comment: This is definitely the best answer. Simple and beautiful. Thank u! Perhaps instead of Locale.US I would use Locale.getDefault().

Comment: `Locale locale = itemView.getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0)`

Answer (score 17):

You are supposed to compare dayOfWeek directly with Calendar.MONDAY etc. See code below

Also, I have put brackets around if else. Do not rely on indentation for code flow, explicitly put brackets even if your if-else has only one statement.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String weekDay = "";

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    if (Calendar.MONDAY == dayOfWeek) {
        weekDay = "monday";
    } else if (Calendar.TUESDAY == dayOfWeek) {
        weekDay = "tuesday";
    } else if (Calendar.WEDNESDAY == dayOfWeek) {
        weekDay = "wednesday";
    } else if (Calendar.THURSDAY == dayOfWeek) {
        weekDay = "thursday";
    } else if (Calendar.FRIDAY == dayOfWeek) {
        weekDay = "friday";
    } else if (Calendar.SATURDAY == dayOfWeek) {
        weekDay = "saturday";
    } else if (Calendar.SUNDAY == dayOfWeek) {
        weekDay = "sunday";
    }

    System.out.println(weekDay);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

There was no need to use the `c.get`

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);                

    if (Calendar.MONDAY == dayOfWeek) weekDay = "monday";
    else if (Calendar.TUESDAY == dayOfWeek) weekDay = "tuesday";
    else if (Calendar.WEDNESDAY == dayOfWeek) weekDay = "wednesday";
    else if (Calendar.THURSDAY == dayOfWeek) weekDay = "thursday";
    else if (Calendar.FRIDAY == dayOfWeek) weekDay = "friday";
    else if (Calendar.SATURDAY == dayOfWeek) weekDay = "saturday";
    else if (Calendar.SUNDAY == dayOfWeek) weekDay = "sunday";

    System.out.println(weekDay);
```

and output:

```
thursday
```

You can see your error if you try to print the values with `c.get` with this code

```
    System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.MONDAY));
    System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.TUESDAY));
    System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.WEDNESDAY));
    System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.THURSDAY));
    System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.FRIDAY));
    System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.SATURDAY));
    System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.SUNDAY));
```

For example I get:

```
7
33
3
15
227
5
2013
```

And the result will be incorrect, in my case I get `Sunday` as `weekDay` if I use your code.

Answer (score 3):

just do the following:

```
    Date date = new Date();
    CharSequence time = DateFormat.format("EEEE", date.getTime()); // gives like (Wednesday)
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;
import java.util.Date;
...
String[] weekdays = new DateFormatSymbols().getWeekdays();
String[] month = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths();
System.outprintln(weekdays[date.getDay()+1]+","+month[date.getMonth()]+" "+date.getDate());
```