# While loop to reduce int in android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to take an int from `SharedPreferences` that tracks how long the app program has been active and reduce it to an int less than 7 to show what day of that program week the user is in.

Here is what I have used to reduce the int, (i am trying to use a while loop to go in and subtract 7 until the int is less than 7. The `IF` statement was added to see if the int was reduced and it was displaying the wrong String)

```
public void methodNameHere() {
        SharedPreferences onvalue = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("TRAININGDAY", MODE_APPEND);
        int day = (int) onvalue.getLong("DAY", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = onvalue.edit();

        while (day < 7) {
            day = day - 7;
        }

        if (day < 7) {
            String da = Integer.toString(day);
            Toast.makeText(CardioStart.this, da, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(CardioStart.this, "f?*k", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

And this is where the int is coming from:

```
private void dayOfTraining() {

        TextView day = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dayoftraining);
        date.setTimeInMillis(millidate);

        Calendar someday = Calendar.getInstance();
        someday.set(2015, 4, 25);

        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        Long millidate = someday.getTimeInMillis();
        long timeTwo = today.getTimeInMillis();
        long oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
        long delta = (timeTwo - millidate) / oneDay;
        long actualday = delta + 1;
        day.setText(Long.toString(actualday));

        SharedPreferences onvalue = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("TRAININGDAY", MODE_APPEND);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = onvalue.edit();
        edit.putLong("DAY", actualday);
        edit.commit();

    }
```

String da toasts as "29" so it seems its not reducing.

I feel like I am missing something simple or I just don't have a true grasp on the use of while loops. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you fix your indentation please?

Comment: Maybe you should learn what the modulo operator (%) is and does...

Comment: `while (day < 7)` sure about that?

Comment: `to show what day of that program week the user is in.` Do you really need all this **machinery** only `to show the current weekday`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/23266940/2649012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The while statement is wrong, you should be checking `while(day > 7) -> do this` not `while(day < 7)` . Code -

```
while (day > 7)
{
day = day - 7;
}
```

Comment: Wow. Just wow. I'm a dummy. Thanks for pointing that out, and not blowing up my spot for being a dunce. Cheers!